# golang mysql exec placeholder "?" not expanded

Tags: mysql, go

I feel like I must be totally missing the point.
I try to run something along the lines of the example below, but the `?` is not expanded into the argument passed in.

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

db, err := sql.Open(...)
if err != nil { ... }
_, err = db.Query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar=?", bar)
```

Also, who's concern is expanding it? it show's up in the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#example_DB_Query) of `database/sql` but other conversations hinted it may be the concern of the driver.

What am I missing? Any pointer in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're (probably) not telling it to use the mysql driver;

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", connString)
```

Here is some of my sample code:

```
var query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO blah (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"

r, err := db.Query(query, some_data_1, some_data_2, some_data_3)

// Failure when trying to store data
if err != nil {
    msg := fmt.Sprintf("fail : %s", err.Error())
    fmt.Println(msg)

    return err
}

r.Close() // Always do this or you will leak connections
```

I create the MySQL pool (yes, it's a pool **NOT** a connection) with:

```
import (
    // mysql driver
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
)

connString := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@(%s:%d)/%s?timeout=30s",
    user,
    password,
    host,
    port,
    database,
)

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", connString)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

err = db.Ping() // test the pool connection(s)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return db, nil // No error, return the pool connections
```

I also highly suggest you print out any errors in the database connection process and query process. It could be that you are using the driver, but you lack permissions, the database is down, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your effort jersten. I was puzzled whether it should work at all, you helped resolving that ambiguity thus I accept the answer. I did not post a very thorough question, and indeed it turns out my question did not contain the issue. It turns out I wanted to pass in the table name as well, which does not seem to be supported. I put together a full working example for anyone's reference. Thanks again!
https://play.golang.org/p/VHTB2zddjl