# Inserting a variable into MySQL with Go

Tags: mysql, go

I have these 2 variables here

```
name := request.FormValue("username")
pass := request.FormValue("password")
```

I want to insert those 2 variables into my database

```
db.Query("INSERT INTO `godb` (`Username`, `Password`) VALUES (   )")
```

I tried `(name,pass)`  `('name','pass')` `($name, $pass)` , none of them work.

Hope the question is not stupid, but I've been looking for solutions online but I did't understand them. Thanks !

Comment: Try placeholders: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781555/golang-mysql-exec-placeholder-not-expanded. And don't store a raw password into a database, hash and salt it first.

Comment: Note that the language has no support for implicit string interpolation of variables accessible in the current scope, as you *seem* to expect. You need to pass the variables to the function explicitly. i.e. `Query("... VALUES (?, ?)", name, pass)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Using Prepared Statements](http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html#parameter-placeholder-syntax)

> **Parameter Placeholder Syntax**
>
> The syntax for placeholder parameters in prepared statements is
> database-specific. For example, comparing MySQL, PostgreSQL, and
> Oracle:
>
> ```
> MySQL               PostgreSQL            Oracle
> =====               ==========            ======
> WHERE col = ?       WHERE col = $1        WHERE col = :col
> VALUES(?, ?, ?)     VALUES($1, $2, $3)    VALUES(:val1, :val2, :val3)
> ```

You tried PostgreSQL syntax but you use MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

query should be in this format
`db.Query("INSERT INTO table ($1, $2) VALUES (column1, column2)", value1, value2)`
in your case something like that
`db.Query("INSERT INTO godb ($1, $2) VALUES (username, password)", name, pass)`

Comment: This is wrong, not only have you switched the order of columns and values but you are also using the wrong parameter references for mysql.